# TypeScript: how to find an object in an array and return that specific object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, find

I'm trying to find an object in an array and return that specific object. I'm new to typescript, so I tried to solve it this way and I'm not sure why it's not working.

Edited: My code is not even being complied! I'm getting the error below:

> TypeScript error in /Users/.../api/VaccineDataApi.tsx(64,14):
> Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

type VaccineDataState = {
    Date: Date,
    Location: string, //Location is state Abbreviations like 'WA'
    LongName: string,
    Doses_Distributed: number,
}

const VaccineData = () => {
    const [vaccine, SetVaccine] = useState<VaccineDataState[]>([])
    const [errorMessage,SetErrorMessage] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://localhost:3000")
        .then((response) => {
            const apiVaccineData = response.data.vaccination_data;
            SetVaccine(apiVaccineData);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            SetErrorMessage(error.message);
            console.log(errorMessage);
        })
    }, []);

  
    let vaccineData = vaccine.find(state => state.Location === 'WA');

    return(
        <div>
            <p>test</p>
            {vaccineData.Location}
        </div>
    )
    
};

export default VaccineData;
```

Comment: This looks correct, what do you get when `console.log(vaccine);`?

Comment: I can't because it's not even compiling: this is the error message: Property 'Location' does not exist on type '() => Element'.  TS2339

Comment: Oky, so the question is not describing what sort of error you are having, update it

Comment: I will do it now, thank you @Kalhan.Toress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VaccineData` refers to the functional component. You probably wanted `vaccineData.Location` instead of `VaccineData.Location`.

Edit: To fix `let vaccineData: VaccineDataState | undefined Object is possibly 'undefined'`, you could:

Add `!` to tell the Typescript compiler that `vaccineData` will never be `undefined` (only if you are sure that it never actually is):

`let vaccineData = vaccine.find(state => state.Location === 'WA')!;`

or

Add some code to check for `undefined`:

```
    let vaccineData = vaccine.find(state => state.Location === 'WA');
    if(!vaccineData)
        return <p>Data not found!</p>;
```

Comment: I tried that but then I'm facing this error 'let vaccineData: VaccineDataState | undefined
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)'

Comment: @Nr that's right.  `find` returns an optional.  Try a conditional.

Comment: @tmwilliamlin168 Your answer solved it! thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: you're right @Christopher I should've noticed that